# Can´t connect with SignalR Angular implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr-hub

I try to implement SignalR using Angular so I follow this [tutorial](http://mahedee.net/a-signalr-application-for-real-time-notification-using-angularjs-and-toastr/). In my app.js I have something like this:

```
 var app = angular.module('portalTransporte', ['common.core', 'common.ui'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run)

    $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });


    $.connection.hub.error(function (err) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + err);
    });

    angular.module('portalTransporte')
       .value('notification', $.connection.notification)
       .value('toastr', toastr);

/* Setup global settings */
    app.factory('settings', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        // supported languages
        var settings = {
            layout: {
                pageSidebarClosed: false, // sidebar menu state
                pageContentWhite: true, // set page content layout
                pageBodySolid: false, // solid body color state
                pageAutoScrollOnLoad: 1000 // auto scroll to top on page load
            },
            assetsPath: '../Metronic',
            globalPath: '../Metronic/global',
            layoutPath: '../Metronic/layouts/layout',
            origen: 'Web',
            version: '0.1W'
        };
        $rootScope.settings = settings;

        return settings;
    }]);

    config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'cfpLoadingBarProvider'];
    function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
        //console.log("config");
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false;
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = true;
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.loadingBarTemplate = '<div id="loading-bar"><div class="bar"><div class="peg"></div></div></div>';
        //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard.html");
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
            var $state = $injector.get("$state");
            $state.go("root.dashboard");
        });

        $stateProvider
    .state('root.cliente_viaje_solicitud_detalle', {
                url: "viajes_c/solicitud/detalle.html",
                templateUrl: "../SPA/viajes_clientes/solicituddetalleCliente.html",
                controller: "solicituddetalleClienteCtrl",
                authenticate: true,
                data: { pageTitle: 'FLETERISTAS - DETALLE DE SOLICITUD' },
                params: {
                    modo: "nuevo",
                    viajeId: null
                }
```

and in JS I call function like this:

```
solicituddetalleClienteCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'apiService', 'notificationService', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', '$stateParams', '$state', 'limitToFilter', 'notification', 'toastr'];

    function solicituddetalleClienteCtrl($scope, apiService, notificationService, $rootScope, $location, $http, $stateParams, $state, limitToFilter, notification, toastr) {
$scope.guardar = function () {
            var inputval = "NewvTrip added";
            notification.server.pushNotification(inputval);
            $scope.newMessage = "";
        };

 notification.client.response = function onNewMessage(message) {
            displayMessage(message);
            $scope.$apply();
        };

        function displayMessage(message) {
            toastr.success(message); //To nofiy as fadin and fadout
        }
```

I debbug it into chrome and when It reach this line  `notification.server.pushNotification(inputval);` it always throw me

> SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call
>   .start() before .send()

Can someone help? Regards . I can share my desktop via Skype or Chrome remote

[image]

I don´t see anything wrong when I call hub. But I prety sure problem is into app.js, I see related questions, but I didn´t find solution

Comment: what is the 'notification' variable? I dont see it anywhere else in your code.

Comment: it´s injected, I added coded in js @Dylan